# WP7 Limit on Number of MediaElements

Tags: windows-phone-7, mediaelement

What is the limit on the number of MediaElements objects per app?
I want to add about 50 MediaElements, all short audio recordings of words or phrases.
I can add 10 and they will play OK. If I try to add more, I don't get any build errors, but
they will not play, just silence. I am testing with the emulator. The objects are being added per the 
following example:

```
        two = new MediaElement();
        two.AutoPlay = false;
        two.Source = new Uri("Sounds/two.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
        two.Volume = volume;
        two.MediaEnded += new RoutedEventHandler(Sound_MediaEnded);
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(two);
        two.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Any idea what limit or problem I am hitting?

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information here to pinpoint your precise issue but you'll probably be better off if you simply create a single `MediaElement` and updating it's source, rather than creating multiple instances.
I have heard that you shouldn't have more than one MediaElement on a single page but have no evidence/source for this.
I'd expect you to have memory issues (or at least be using a lot more memory than need be) if you're creating lots of instances of a MediaElement.